# pagination error undefined variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm working on a pagination function but it gives me an `undefined variable error`. Could someone help me, please?

My controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        // Call the Controller constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library("pagination");
        $this->load->model('place');
        $this->load->model('place_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        session_start();
    }

    function manage()
    {
        $this->load->model('Place_model');
        $per_page = 5;
        $total = $this->Place_model->count_posts();

        $base_url = site_url('home/search');
        $config['base_url'] = $base_url;
        $config['total_rows'] = $total;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $config['uri_segment'] = '3';
        $data['posts'] = $this->Place_model->get_posts($per_page, $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
        $this->load->view('search_result_page', $data);
    }
}
```

My model is `place_model`:

```
class Place_model extends CI_Model 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Place');
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function get_posts($limit = NULL, $offset = NULL) 
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $qPlace = $this->db->get('place');
        return $qPlace;
    }

    function count_posts()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all_results('place');
    }
}
```

My view is `search_result_page`:

```
</div>  
<?php
foreach ($posts->results() as $place):
    echo $place->name, '<br />';
    echo $place->placeID;
endforeach;
?>
</div>  
</pre>   
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

It gives me error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: posts

Filename: views/search_result_page.php

Line Number: 100
```

I think this line:

```
$data['posts'] = $this->Place_model->get_posts($per_page, $this->uri->segment(3));
```

gives me `null`, I have no idea how to solve it.

Could someone help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: you can do var_dump($post) in your view to see if it has any data.

Comment: It gives me null. I know it does not has any data, but I don't know how to fix it. There might be something wrong with controller code, I think...

Comment: try this instead, `$qPlace = $this->db->get('place',$limit,$offset);`

Answer (score 5):

```
$data['posts'] = $this->Place_model->get_posts($per_page, $this->uri->segment(3));
//change this to 
$data['posts'] = $this->place_model->get_posts($per_page, $this->uri->segment(3));
```

i also got the same error and i solved it by using small letter on the model not capital